# nlapiRequestURL returning http code 400 Invalid parameter combination

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, sap-concur

I have a Netsuite scheduled script that connects to Concurs API to revoke all tokens for a user but I am getting a response code of 400 Invalid parameter combination.  I have tried many different ways of setting the parameters but, I am having no luck.

Concur's Documentation says that this is what the need:

ConsumerKey: The access token of which you wish to revoke all current and future access.
User: The login Id of the token owner.
Format:

```
POST https://{InstanceURL}/net2/oauth2/revoketoken.ashx?consumerKey={Consumer Key}&user={User}
Authorization: OAuth {Token}
```

Here is my code

```js
 var headers = {};
 headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
 headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
 headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + credentials;
 headers['X-ConsumerKey'] = key; 
 headers.Authorization = 'OAuth ' + token;

 var urlpassed='revoketoken.ashx?consumerKey='+ key +'&user=WebAdmin%40redfin.com';
 var revokeToken = nlapiRequestURL('https://concursolutions.com/net2/oauth2/revoketoken.ashx?consumerKey='+ key +'&user='+ user,'', headers, 'POST');
```

Comment: Have you tried posting to the url via another method like using Postman, or another tool where you can test and inspect url responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Concur Docs](https://developer.concur.com/api-reference/authentication/authentication.html#revoke-all-access-tokens) you should add `consumerKey` and `user` as parameter as in the below code snippet:

```
nlapiRequestURL('https://www.concursolutions.com/net2/oauth2/revoketoken.ashx?consumerKey='
    + YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY + '&user=' + YOUR_LOGIN_USER_ID, 
  '', 
  {'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + token}, 'POST');
```

For the above code I got 200 OK in my case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:  I was doing everything correct but miss typed the URL leaving out  "www." - stupid typo.